# How to open GNU GRUB with timeout 0 and default boot set to memtest?

Tags: boot, grub2

So I was updating the `/etc/default/grub` file and was trying to make the boot time faster, so I set the `timeout=0`. I also set the default boot to memtest by accident.

After updating the grub and rebooting I am now stuck booting the memtest. I can't seem to force the GNU grub by holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> or any other button and after some search this seems to not be an option with `timeout=0`.

Is there some way to open the GNU grub from memtest or some other way to force it to open on boot?

Comment: Have you tried holding shift _and_ an arrow key (e.g. arrow down)?

Comment: I would suggest booting a 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media), and then mounting or disk, navigating to the '/boot/grub' directory and just editing the file directly, it'll then allow you to select Ubuntu, where you can fix it the way you want...

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to edit GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0

Sudo into /etc/default/grub - find that entry and comment out or set timeout back to 10. Save and exit then reboot.
Hold the shift key down after the bios boots.

Once you're on the boot screen you can choose from the menu options to hopefully fix your issue. You can go back into /etc/default/grub afterwards and uncomment the timeout line or back to =0

Have fun